# How do i pass blob / any binary file from js client to flask server and decode it properly

Tags: javascript, python, flask, blob

im am relativly new to flask AND js..

Trying to get blob from a video recorder, and save it to a video file on the server side:

recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
mimeType: 'video/webm',
bitsPerSecond: 128000
});
...
...
let blob = recorder.getBlob();
..
..

**AND send to flask**:

var form = $('<form style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0; display: none;
visibility: hidden;" method="POST"; enctype="multipart/form-data"; action= "{{
url_for("users.user_question", filename=video_blob) }}">');

```
 form.append('<input type="hidden" name="video" value='+blob+'>');
 $("body").append(form);
 form.submit();
```

...
**Flask gets something** (not sure how to verify its a real video binary (?)):

...

...

data =  request.form.getlist('video')

...

#print data -> shows this: ['[object']

```
if data:

    with open("c:/test/file.webm", "wb") as vid:
            video_stream = bytes(data)#request.files['video'].read()
            vid.write(video_stream)
            return Response()
```

**Getting error**: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

1. is this the right approach for doing file trasnfers between client and flask?
2. how can i make sure its a real binary file and save it as video?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the right approach. You can't just splat the blob into an input field and hope for the best.

You might be able to concoct a `FormData` object and use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to post it:

```
const url = "{{ url_for("users.user_question", filename=video_blob) }}";
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("video", blob);
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
}).then(res => {
  if(res.ok) alert('OK!');
}).catch(err => {
  alert(err);   
});
```

Regarding the format of the binary data, that's up to the library that generates it. The [documentation](https://recordrtc.org/RecordRTCPromisesHandler.html) doesn't make it very clear though.

Comment: thank you, this really helped and i am getting "somthing" that seems to be a blob, but the file is saved into a 1 kb mpeg file.  i will check and if necessary will open a new qustion.